# Nesting PHP inside PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

So I have this

```
 echo "<a class='btn btn-primary' href=''>Read more...</a>";
```

in a PHP loop and I want to do something like this:

```
<a class='btn btn-primary' href=“single.php?news=<?php echo “$row[‘codn’] ?>”>Read more...</a>
```

How can I easily do it?

Comment: You don't go into php mode again - you're already in it. Concat the strings instead. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Never ever use curly quotes (single or double) in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concat as below

```
 echo "<a class='btn btn-primary' href='single.php?news=".$row['codn']."'>Read more...</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this inside the loop:

```
echo "<a class='btn btn-primary' href='single.php?news=" . $row['codn']. "'>Read more...</a>";
```